# How to rename a Image folder name in android Build.VERSION_CODES.R?

Tags: android, sdk, file-rename

Below is my code.AlertDialog Dialog ask me Allow to modify this photo?.But after that file not get renaming..

```
                            val sourceFile = File(ext)
                            val destFile = File(edt.text.toString())
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                                val ext =
                                    File(bucketData.buckedPath)
                               
                                val from = File(ext, edt.text.toString())
                                ext.renameTo(from)

                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {



                                    var mUri =
                                        FileActionUtils.getImageUriFromFile(
                                            bucketData.buckedPath,
                                            this@MainActivity
                                        )
                                    val uriList: List<Uri> = listOf(mUri
                                       )
                                    val pi = MediaStore.createWriteRequest(contentResolver, uriList)
                                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                                        pi.intentSender, 124,
                                        null, 0, 0, 0, null
                                    )
                                }
```

Comment: `val destFile = File(edt.text.toString())`  We do not know what the user typed in. So please use a hard coded string instead for this forum.

Comment: `val destFile = File(edt.text.toString())` Also we do not know the value for `ext`. So please start with that variable in your post.

Comment: `File(bucketData.buckedPath)` ..... the same./.. we dont know what that would be. Post reproducable code to begin with!